# How to change the space between the itemize items in latex?

Tags: latex, pdflatex

In Latex, how can I change change the space between the `{itemize}` "items" globally, such that I can continue to use the "itemize" and "item" tag without needing to redefine any new tags?

Comment: Please don't cross post. http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12373/how-to-change-the-space-between-the-itemize-items-in-latex

Answer (score 34):

You could set the separating space inside an itemize environment.

```
\begin{itemize}
  \setlength{\itemsep}{5pt}

  \item Item1
  \item Item2
\end{itemize}
```

Alternatively, afaik, you would need to create your own environment.

Comment: How can I create my own environment?

Comment: Take a look at this page: [link](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Formatting#Customizing_Lists)